# Use parent's Makefile to compile the sub-directory

Tags: makefile

The 1st line of my `Makefile` is:

> include def.mk

This gives me the flexibility to define the dependencies inside `def.mk` and leave the `Makefile` as generic as possible.

Currently I am defining a def.mk under each of submodules. But I am **duplicating** the entire Makefile.

- Is it possible to have only one `Makefile` in the parent directory and each sub-directory to have **only** `def.mk` such that the parent directory's `Makefile` is used to compile sub-directory?
- Or, is it possible to have a minimal `Makefile` under each of the sub-directories, which in-turn uses the parent's `Makefile`
- Also, the `Makefile` need to use the `def.mk` defined in the respective directories and not the parent's.

**PS**: Unfortunately, I don't have the luxury to use any of the `automake` tools. These Makefiles have to be hand-crafted! :(

**PPS**: Also, I do have sub-directories more than one-level deep.

Comment: Yes, all of these are possible. Would you like to hear about all of these, or does one of them in particular appeal to you? What do you want your makefile system to *do?*

Comment: @Beta: The very first one, i.e.,
_Is it possible to have only one Makefile in the parent directory and each sub-directory to have only def.mk such that the parent directory's Makefile is used to compile sub-directory?_

Comment: All right, now suppose you have `main/Makefile` and `main/subOne/def.mk`. Where do you want to run Make, what parameters do you want to give it and what do you want it to do?

Comment: oh! did I miss out that I need it recursive?! :( Damn! I will edit the question to include that part. So, suppose i have `main/Makefile` and `main/subOne/def.mk` & `main/subTwo/def.mk`. Now, when I run `make` in _main_, it should recursively make the _subOne_ as well as _subTwo_ **using the main/Makefile & the corresponding def.mk**

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to do it.

Suppose we have `main/Makefile`, `main/subOne/def.mk`, `main/subTwo/def.mk` and `main/subOne/subThree/def.mk`, and various source and header files (`foo.cc` and `bar.h`).

First we must decide how Make will know which targets to build, and which subdirectories to recurse into, in each directory. The safest way is to list them in the corresponding `def.mk` files.

Then the big question: **recursive or non-recursive?**

Recursive Make (when Make executes another instance of Make) is *crude but effective*. It leads to simpler makefiles, but prevents Make from using its dependency-handling to full effect, so that the build process may be inefficient. (Many consider Recursive Make just plain bad for this reason, but I think it has its uses.)

`Makefile`:

```
SUBDIRS := subOne subTwo

-include def.mk

all: $(SUBDIRS)

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS):
    @make -C $@ -f ../$(STACK)Makefile STACK=../$(STACK)
```

Notice that the variable `STACK` (or whatever you want to call it) keeps track of the path back up to the makefile.

`subOne/def.mk`:

```
SUBDIRS := subThree

all: alpha.o

alpha.o: alpha.h
```

`subTwo/def.mk`:

```
SUBDIRS :=

all: beta.o

beta.o: beta.h
```

`subOne/subThree/def.mk`:

```
SUBDIRS :=

all: gamma.o delta.o

gamma.o: gamma.h
delta.o: delta.h gamma.h
```

The non-recursive version is a little more complex, but I'll add it if you're game...

Comment: It would have been nice if you had at least posted a link describing non-recursive make. Especially considering you called your own answer "just plain bad" in comparison.

Comment: @Dan: "A link describing non-recursive make"? I honestly don't know what you think such a link would point to. (And I didn't call my own answer "just plain bad" in comparison.)

Comment: "Many consider Recursive Make just plain bad" .. "The non-recursive version is a little more complex, but I'll add it if you're game..." That, to me, implied that "non-recursive make" is better (otherwise, why did you mention it at all?) If that's not the case, perhaps reword the answer or remove that last sentence altogether?